# check if comment submitted was successful

Tags: php, comments

I want to use php to understand if comment submission was successful. Is there any `get/post` data I can use to make `if` function for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_insert_comment($data);` function to check your [comment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment) is submit or not.

This function will return

**(integer) The new comment's ID.** on success &  **(boolean)  `false` if the insert failed.**

Hope this will helps you